# how to send tcp message to remote server using socket.io

Tags: node.js, tcp, socket.io

my friend and I are both using the same wifi network with open ports for both of us. My friend is listening on port 8000 and I'd like to send him a message.
How can I achieve that using node and socket.io ? Thanks a lot

Comment: https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to setup a simple messenger, the standard one is to setup a single socket.io server either on your or your friend's machine, something like this:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("user connected!")
  socket.on('message', function (message) {
    //Sends message to all connected sockets
    socket.broadcast.emit("message")
  });
});
```

Then your index.html should have some code for connecting to server and sending messages:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://server-ip-or-domain-name:port');
  socket.on('message', function (message) {
    //processing incoming message here
    console.log(message);
  });

  function sendMessage(msg){
      //sends message to server
      socket.emit("message", msg);
  }
</script>
```

In this setup both you and your friend should be able to reach the server machine. Use pings for debuging.

p.s. havent tested the code above, but that's the idea.

Comment: pings are bad idea since it use ICMP packages and not the actual port used by the websocket protocol. Better tool for that commitment is netcat `nc -zv hostname port`